# Browser support for a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html, photo

I have a function which takes an image as a input and returns it as a 200 x 200 size.
It's working on local platform on Chrome. But not working on Safari by **codepen** site.

https://codepen.io/sbrakeshrath/pen/PoprEqP?editors=1011

I don't know why.

Honestly my friend said that but I can't test as I have no Mac devices.

Can you look at my code and say what's wrong with it and the browser support for entire code?

#### Another Favor

Can you say am I doing it on the right way or any other possibility is there?

```js
const Pro_pic = document.querySelector("img");
// console.log(Pro_pic);



function changeProfilePic(e, Pro_pic, form) {
  console.log("hallo");
  const pic_dim = {
    w: 250,
    h: 250,
  };
  const imgIn = document.createElement("input");
  imgIn.type = "file";
  imgIn.accept = "image/*";
  imgIn.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const objUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = objUrl;
    img.onload = (e) => {
      const ratio = {
        h: img.height / img.width,

        v: img.width / img.height,
      };

      // canvas element

      const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      canvas.width = pic_dim.w;
      canvas.height = pic_dim.h;
      const newImfDim = {
        w: 0,
        h: 0,
      };

      if (ratio.v < 1) {
        newImfDim.w = pic_dim.w;
        newImfDim.h = pic_dim.h / ratio.v;
      } else {
        newImfDim.w = pic_dim.w / ratio.h;
        newImfDim.h = pic_dim.h;
      }

      console.log(newImfDim);
      canvas.style.margin = "20px 20px";
      ctx.drawImage(
        img,
        -(newImfDim.w - pic_dim.w) / 2,
        -(newImfDim.h - pic_dim.h) / 2,
        newImfDim.w,
        newImfDim.h
      );

      Pro_pic.src = canvas.toDataURL();
      form.insertBefore(canvas, form.firstChild);
    };
  });
  imgIn.click();
}

function clicked(e){
  changeProfilePic(e, Pro_pic, document.body);
}
```

```html
<img src= "" />
<button onclick = "clicked(event)"> click to change pic</button>
```

Comment: You can use browserstack.com to test your code on different browsers.

Comment: so charles how safari takes input type file

Comment: The user can put the file into an input. Javascript can't.

Comment: so my function is useLess on safari ??? how to fix this bug

Comment: @CharlesBamford I don't believe that's correct. The `Blob` and `File` APIs in the DOM work fine in Safari (both macOS and iOS) for me.

Comment: I die inside every time I see people use `canvas.toDataURL()` instead of `toBlob()` - because `data:` URIs are **not** how multi-megabyte binaries should be saved.

Comment: can you explain Dai what are u trying to say

Comment: @Rakesh Please elaborate on what "doesn't work" means. The code is running fine for me in Safari.

Comment: @Dai I believe Charles is correct; you can't prepopulate an `input type="file"` with a value. But the OP isn't doing that here. They merely setup the `onchange` handler and call the `input`'s `click` handler, which by default will display the OS's file chooser dialog. The user still needs to select an image.

Comment: so Heretic my function will work on safari ??????

Comment: As @skyline3000 says, it appears so. I see nothing in the code that shouldn't work in recent versions of Safari. Ask your friend to provide errors that occur when they run it, and what version of Satari they are running. And take it easy on your question mark key ;).

Comment: Is this a good way to compress user photo on frontend level ?